# Customizing Google Place Picker widget

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

I am currently trying to create a MapView which would have 80% exact same functionality as [Places Picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker) which is provided by google.

I am seeking all the way to find a way to customise this UI widget or the source code so that I could do exactly what its doing.

Anybody have any idea?

Comment: The `GMSPlacePicker` only has a `GMSPlacePickerConfig` property which allow you to configure the picker, however, the config is not for picker UI. If you want to use a custom UI, you can make your own `UIPickerView`, and the data can come from the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro).

Comment: So that is what I am thinking there is no way to config the UI. But do you know any good open source code for similar functionality?

Comment: It totally depends on how you want to customize your UI. You can search in cocoacontrols.com, if you want picker based, you can see [this list of results](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=picker) or [tableview based](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=table).

Comment: Thanks ztan, the website you recommended is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

The [getCurrentPlace() method](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/current-place) will return an ordered list of Places at which the API believes the device to be located. This is the same list as is displayed in the PlacePicker, so using the data returned from this API with a UITableView, it should be fairly simple to build your own UI.

Comment: Thanks for you answer plexer. Do you know any good open source code for this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any.